# Codemirror Dynamically Adding JS SRC via HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/YXhggg

What I've been trying to do is simple. I want to add the following code dynamically into Codemirror.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>\n
```

It works fine if I don't add the script's HTML. [example](http://liveweave.com/AXma0f)

```
$(".jquery").click(function() {
  editor.setCursor({line: 5 , ch : 0 });
  editor.replaceRange("TAA DAA\n", editor.getCursor()); 
  editor.focus();
});
```

But when I do this is what happens.

[image]

Console returns with: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` defying the line error to be the following code.

```
editor.replaceRange("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>\n", editor.getCursor());
```

The problem continues to be with `</script>` within the code I'm trying to add dynamically.

I thought maybe using the less than and greater than signs may fix the problem...

```
editor.replaceRange("&lt;script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n", editor.getCursor());
```

but didn't

[image]

I'm confused on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle - http://liveweave.com/EyC98j

I took a look at Liveweave's source code to see how they did it.

Liveweave looks for your `<head>` tag and adds your library right below it. If it doesn't have a head tag they alert you with a dialog suggestion.

```
  // Append JS library to HTML <head>
  function appendJSLib(txt) {
  var textArea=htmlEditor.getValue();
        var searchText = textArea.search("<head>");
        if(searchText>0) {
        txt = "<head>"+"\n"+txt;
        var updatedTextArea = textArea.replace("<head>",txt);
        htmlEditor.setValue(updatedTextArea);
        }
        else {
        reset();
        alertify.alert("<span style='color: #f5f5f5; padding:4px 6px 4px 6px; border-radius:3px; background-color: #cc0000;'>WARNING!</span><br/><br/> The <strong>&lt;head&gt;</strong> tag seems to be missing in your HTML. Although your code may still work, we highly recommened that you have a valid HTML syntax. Please refer to the structure of a correct HTML code below:<br/><br/>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br/>&lt;html&gt;<br/>&lt;head&gt;<br/>&lt;title&gt&lt;!-- title --&gt;&lt;/title&gt;<br/> &lt;/head&gt;<br/> &lt;body&gt;<br/> &lt;!-- your content here --&gt;<br/> &lt;/body&gt;<br/>&lt;/html&gt;");
        txt = txt+textArea;
        htmlEditor.setLine(0, txt);
        return false;
        }
  }
```

In my case all I needed was a forward slash right after the `</` in `</script>` to close the code like so..

```
editor.replaceRange("<"+"script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js\">"+"</"+"script"+">\n", editor.getCursor());
```

If you'd like to go Liveweave's way you would add a js library like so.

```
$("#jquery").click(function() {
  txt="<"+"script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js\">"+"</"+"script"+">";
  appendJSLib(txt);
});
```